# Examples for using Nvidia FXAA (shader antialiasing) in XNA 4.0 winforms?

Tags: xna, antialiasing

I'm using this example project's XNA 4.0 form control in an application I'm writing: http://creators.xna.com/en-US/sample/winforms_series1

If you are unfamiliar with FXAA, check out the creator's site:
http://timothylottes.blogspot.com/2011/03/nvidia-fxaa.html

I've spent quite a bit of time so far trying to figure out to use it without any luck (so far...).  It's true I don't have much experience at all with graphics programming, but I do currently have a nice application running, it just looks really really poor with the jagged lines.  I know about the built-in method for AA, but doesn't work for me and my laptop computer.  So my request is about using FXAA and not the built-in methods.

At this point:
I have FXAA 3.11 header file in my Content project.
I have a generic FX file generated by visual studio with a few things like:

```
#define FXAA_PC_CONSOLE 1
#define FXAA_HLSL_5 1
#define FXAA_QUALITY__PRESET 12
#include "Includes/Fxaa3_11.h"
```

I'm just asking here to see if anyone could provide some XNA 4.0 examples, specifically with using that custom windows forms method.

I appreciate any help someone might be able to provide.

**Edit 3:**
I've been trying to work out how to get FXAA working since I posted this message.
I found this: 
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/609638-fxaa-help/page__st__20
and this: 
http://fxaa-pp-inject.assembla.me/trunk/DirectX9/shader.fx

I striped down FXAA to bare bones FXAA_PC_CONSOLE type and it compiles.  I just need to figure out the parameter fxaaConsolePosPos that is the top left and bottom right position of each pixel.  Anyways, it looks like FXAA_PC_CONSOLE might work with shader model 2.0 that I need to use with REACH and winforms based XNA.

Comment: Is MLAA an option for you?  I don't think that you'll find an example of code using the WinForms example plus FXAA in a tutorial.

Comment: Anything but the built-in antialiasing should be an option if it works on lesser hardware.  Do you know of where I could find something for xna winforms an MLAA?

Comment: Well really anything with XNA at all (as long as it doesn't use the game class and such)...  I haven't found anything yet and I'm still trying to just work it out myself by learning as much as I can about xna shaders

Comment: Take a look at http://xnafinalengine.codeplex.com, as they have implemented MLAA, but this isn't in a WinForms environment.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I had seen that project before and skimmed through it.  The issue with it right now is that it uses pixel shader version 3 and I have to use xna "reach" rendering that can only use version 2.

Comment: I updated my posting with an answer because I figured it out. :)

Comment: Excellent!  Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Here is a photo: http://www.flickr.com/photos/dslrninja/6242639960/sizes/o/in/photostream/
Not sure I'm doing everything right, but there is a noticeable difference.  I think I need to do something like render at 2x the size of my window and down-size to get rid of those large jagged lines.

Comment: Not sure if you are using it or not, but try: `graphicsDevice.PreferMultiSampling = true;`
This may help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I figured it out, at least using the lesser version of FXAA designed for consoles and low-end PCs.  I can't guarantee my parameters to the shader code are correct, but I do see a noticeable difference when it is running.

Here is the complete solution with my chopped up shader and pieces of the C# XNA 4.0 code:

The shader code first (put that in a .fx file in your Content sub-project):
**note that I replaced tex2Dlod with tex2D as per a suggestion that SM2.0 doesn't support the first type**

```
#define FxaaBool bool
#define FxaaDiscard clip(-1)
#define FxaaFloat float
#define FxaaFloat2 float2
#define FxaaFloat3 float3
#define FxaaFloat4 float4
#define FxaaHalf half
#define FxaaHalf2 half2
#define FxaaHalf3 half3
#define FxaaHalf4 half4
#define FxaaSat(x) saturate(x)

#define FxaaInt2 float2
#define FxaaTex sampler2D
#define FxaaTexTop(t, p) tex2D(t, float4(p, 0.0, 0.0))
#define FxaaTexOff(t, p, o, r) tex2D(t, float4(p + (o * r), 0, 0))

FxaaFloat FxaaLuma(FxaaFloat4 rgba) { 
    rgba.w = dot(rgba.rgb, FxaaFloat3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
return  rgba.w; }

/*============================================================================
                         FXAA3 CONSOLE - PC VERSION
============================================================================*/
FxaaFloat4 FxaaPixelShader(
    FxaaFloat2 pos,
    FxaaFloat4 fxaaConsolePosPos,
    FxaaTex tex,
    FxaaFloat4 fxaaConsoleRcpFrameOpt,
    FxaaFloat4 fxaaConsoleRcpFrameOpt2,
    FxaaFloat fxaaConsoleEdgeSharpness,
    FxaaFloat fxaaConsoleEdgeThreshold,
    FxaaFloat fxaaConsoleEdgeThresholdMin) {
    FxaaFloat lumaNw = FxaaLuma(FxaaTexTop(tex, fxaaConsolePosPos.xy));
    FxaaFloat lumaSw = FxaaLuma(FxaaTexTop(tex, fxaaConsolePosPos.xw));
    FxaaFloat lumaNe = FxaaLuma(FxaaTexTop(tex, fxaaConsolePosPos.zy));
    FxaaFloat lumaSe = FxaaLuma(FxaaTexTop(tex, fxaaConsolePosPos.zw));
    FxaaFloat4 rgbyM = FxaaTexTop(tex, pos.xy);
    #if (FXAA_GREEN_AS_LUMA == 0)
        FxaaFloat lumaM = rgbyM.w;
    #else
        FxaaFloat lumaM = rgbyM.y;
    #endif
    FxaaFloat lumaMaxNwSw = max(lumaNw, lumaSw);
    lumaNe += 1.0/384.0;
    FxaaFloat lumaMinNwSw = min(lumaNw, lumaSw);
    FxaaFloat lumaMaxNeSe = max(lumaNe, lumaSe);
    FxaaFloat lumaMinNeSe = min(lumaNe, lumaSe);
    FxaaFloat lumaMax = max(lumaMaxNeSe, lumaMaxNwSw);
    FxaaFloat lumaMin = min(lumaMinNeSe, lumaMinNwSw);
    FxaaFloat lumaMaxScaled = lumaMax * fxaaConsoleEdgeThreshold;
    FxaaFloat lumaMinM = min(lumaMin, lumaM);
    FxaaFloat lumaMaxScaledClamped = max(fxaaConsoleEdgeThresholdMin, lumaMaxScaled);
    FxaaFloat lumaMaxM = max(lumaMax, lumaM);
    FxaaFloat dirSwMinusNe = lumaSw - lumaNe;
    FxaaFloat lumaMaxSubMinM = lumaMaxM - lumaMinM;
    FxaaFloat dirSeMinusNw = lumaSe - lumaNw;
    if(lumaMaxSubMinM < lumaMaxScaledClamped) return rgbyM;
    FxaaFloat2 dir;
    dir.x = dirSwMinusNe + dirSeMinusNw;
    dir.y = dirSwMinusNe - dirSeMinusNw;
    FxaaFloat2 dir1 = normalize(dir.xy);
    FxaaFloat4 rgbyN1 = FxaaTexTop(tex, pos.xy - dir1 * fxaaConsoleRcpFrameOpt.zw);
    FxaaFloat4 rgbyP1 = FxaaTexTop(tex, pos.xy + dir1 * fxaaConsoleRcpFrameOpt.zw);
    FxaaFloat dirAbsMinTimesC = min(abs(dir1.x), abs(dir1.y)) * fxaaConsoleEdgeSharpness;
    FxaaFloat2 dir2 = clamp(dir1.xy / dirAbsMinTimesC, -2.0, 2.0);
    FxaaFloat4 rgbyN2 = FxaaTexTop(tex, pos.xy - dir2 * fxaaConsoleRcpFrameOpt2.zw);
    FxaaFloat4 rgbyP2 = FxaaTexTop(tex, pos.xy + dir2 * fxaaConsoleRcpFrameOpt2.zw);
    FxaaFloat4 rgbyA = rgbyN1 + rgbyP1;
    FxaaFloat4 rgbyB = ((rgbyN2 + rgbyP2) * 0.25) + (rgbyA * 0.25);
    #if (FXAA_GREEN_AS_LUMA == 0)
        FxaaBool twoTap = (rgbyB.w < lumaMin) || (rgbyB.w > lumaMax);
    #else
        FxaaBool twoTap = (rgbyB.y < lumaMin) || (rgbyB.y > lumaMax);
    #endif
    if(twoTap) rgbyB.xyz = rgbyA.xyz * 0.5;
    return rgbyB; 
}
/*==========================================================================*/

uniform extern float SCREEN_WIDTH;
uniform extern float SCREEN_HEIGHT;
uniform extern texture gScreenTexture;

sampler screenSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <gScreenTexture>;
    /*MinFilter = LINEAR;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;*/
};

float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 tc : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float pixelWidth = (1 / SCREEN_WIDTH);
    float pixelHeight = (1 / SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    float2 pixelCenter = float2(tc.x - pixelWidth, tc.y - pixelHeight);
    float4 fxaaConsolePosPos = float4(tc.x, tc.y, tc.x + pixelWidth, tc.y + pixelHeight);

    return FxaaPixelShader(
        pixelCenter,
        fxaaConsolePosPos,
        screenSampler,
        float4(-0.50 / SCREEN_WIDTH, -0.50 / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.50 / SCREEN_WIDTH, 0.50 / SCREEN_HEIGHT),
        float4(-2.0 / SCREEN_WIDTH, -2.0 / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 2.0 / SCREEN_WIDTH, 2.0 / SCREEN_HEIGHT),
        8.0,
        0.125,
        0.05);
}

technique ppfxaa
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of C-sharp code to apply the shader:

```
//..........................................
//these objects are used in managing the FXAA operation

//FXAA objects (anti-aliasing)
RenderTarget2D renderTarget;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Effect fxaaAntialiasing;

//..........................................
//initialize the render target and set effect parameters

//code to handle a final antialiasing using a pixel shader
renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(
    GraphicsDevice,
    GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
    GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
    false,
    GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat,
    DepthFormat.Depth24);

spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
fxaaAntialiasing = content.Load<Effect>("sfxaa");
fxaaAntialiasing.CurrentTechnique = fxaaAntialiasing.Techniques["ppfxaa"];
fxaaAntialiasing.Parameters["SCREEN_WIDTH"].SetValue(renderTarget.Width);
fxaaAntialiasing.Parameters["SCREEN_HEIGHT"].SetValue(renderTarget.Height);
fxaaAntialiasing.Parameters["gScreenTexture"].SetValue(renderTarget as Texture2D);


//..........................................
//this should happen in your Draw() method

//change to our offscreen render target
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

//
//draw all of your models and such here...
//

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

//this where the shader antialiasing happens to the frame we just filled with content
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
    SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, 
    RasterizerState.CullNone, fxaaAntialiasing);

//draw the buffer we made to the screen
spriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget as Texture2D, 
    new Rectangle(0, 0, renderTarget.Width, renderTarget.Height), 
    Color.White);

spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm going to attempt to implement FXAA as a PixelShader for use in WPF projects. In a project I am working on, I have a lot of bitmap-level manipulations and want to apply a pixelshader to assist with smoothing out the jagged edges. 

WPF supports PS3.0 and Silverlight supports PS2.0 in the built in ShaderEffect type. Do you have any experience with either WPF/SL and would you mind if I asked a few questions if and when I get stuck on development?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used WPF/Silverlight.  Basically for this project I spent a few weeks off and on researching the issue because there so little information and only did enough to get it working.  I don't think I could be of much help.

Comment: Getting an exception in the forelast line SpriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget...): System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.' Any ideas someone?

Answer (score -2):

I implemented this technique into my game recently but for some reason my edges remain "jaggy" still. Is there a way to tweak the code somewhere to soften the jagged edges somewhat? Thank you.

Comment: Not answering question, please ask new one :)